# Submitting a file via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, upload, file-io

Started with ajax last week. How would I upload an image using it. What I want to do is upload an image. I would imagine using `input type="file"` then the PHP file needs to collect the URL of the newly uploaded image. And return it to the ajax function to put the URL inside an `<img src"" >`

How would one do that.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: Have you tried searching SO for ajax file upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Valums ajax upload script](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).  If it comes across a browser that does not support upload via ajax it will gracefully handle them via hidden iframe uploads

Note: IE (all flavors) does not support file uploads via ajax and will therefore default back to iframe upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send files through AJAX consistently. You will need to submit your form into a hidden iframe to simulate an AJAX transaction. Using an iframe ensures that your application will be compatible with all browsers - particularly the IEs.

After digging through my bookmarks a simple script to facilitate this might be found with http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ but I have not used it.

Comment: That is untrue.  However it is not supported by all browsers (namely IE).  http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: @RDL hmm... see edited answer. Took me a while to find the link I was looking for.

Comment: Please feel free to comment on my answer. Explain exactly why a down vote was considered helpful.

Comment: I have used valums script (recently which is why I beat ya to it ;) ) and it does downgrade nicely to a hidden iframe.  It would be nice if IE caught up with the times but currently IE9 does not support file transfers over XHR either.  Perhaps IE10 but I'm not holding my breath.